# How to use a variable in SQLite query?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sqlite, dapper

I started fooling around with SQLite and Dapper in a Unity project and stumbled across my first problem fairly quickly.
I want to be able to replace certain expression in a query with variables (like in a WHERE condition), for example to filter a list for rows with entries containing a certain string in a certain column.

In my example the database holds first and last name, and a few other values. Now I want to read all the rows that have "Lee" as first name. This works perfectly fine if I just type it manually in a query or if I use a parameter & set the parameter's value to Lee. But if I try to set the parameter's value to a certain string variable (for example from a text input field), it won't work.

```
public void Read(string searchTerm)
{
    Debug.Log("Started searching for: " + searchTerm);
    SqliteConnection dbcon = new SqliteConnection(connection);
    dbcon.Open();

    var results = dbcon.Query<TestSubject>("SELECT * FROM TestTable WHERE first_name LIKE :a", new {a = searchTerm});

    foreach (TestSubject d in results)
    {
        Debug.Log("First Name: " + d.first_name.ToString());
        Debug.Log("Last Name: " + d.last_name.ToString());
        Debug.Log("Age: " + d.age.ToString());
    }

    dbcon.Close();
}
```

As mentioned before, if I use {a = "Lee"}, I get the results, but if I use the above code, where searchTerm = "Lee", I get no results.

I tried different syntax, even looked into dapper (which didn't help with my problem, but made handling results easier). Am I doing something wrong or is this just not possible with SQLite?

EDIT: I should probably mention that the searchTerm string comes from a text input field, and the Read(...) function gets triggered when pressing a "search" button. A vaguely remember having problems before with user generated strings that get implemented in code, but this should be different since it's only executed after the string is already set, right?

EDIT2: I tried something different now. I got the whole table from the query and tried to filter the results with a conditional inside the foreach-expression. Sadly this behaves the same as before - if I use "Lee" instead of searchTerm it works, if I use searchTerm it doesn't. This shows however that the problem is most likely not related to SQLite but to something else.

```
var results = dbcon.Query<TestSubject>("SELECT * FROM TestTable");

foreach (TestSubject d in results)
{
    if (d.first_name.Contains(searchTerm))
    {
        Debug.Log("First Name: " + d.first_name.ToString());
        Debug.Log("Last Name: " + d.last_name.ToString());
        Debug.Log("Age: " + d.age.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a typo here, I remember dapper using `@` not `:`?

Comment: Tried both, both work (when using the actually string "Lee" in the parameter), but neither do when using the variable.. :/

Comment: Did you check with a debugger that the variable actually has the value Lee when you run this code?

Comment: Yeah, it's the first line of the Read(...) function.

Comment: Did you try `searchString.Trim()` ?

Comment: I did now, but that didn't help. Although it's a good tip in general nevertheless, so thanks :)

Comment: But this is a good point. If I directly compare the first_name ("Lee") to the searchTerm ("Lee") it also returns a false. So this definitely has nothing to do with SQLite but with strings and input fields in general.

Comment: What about `first_name.Trim()`? Maybe the database has some whitespace...? What are the datatypes in SQLite, eg first_name?

Comment: I just tried this comparing them again: both trimmed, set to lower case (just in case), ToString() - still nothing. The SQLite datatype for names is "TEXT", for age "INTEGER".

Comment: I used a TextMeshPro-Input field, which probably uses some different encoding or something like that. Using a "normal" input field seems to fix the problem. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The search term should be enclosed in wildcard `%`.

Something like this should work:

```
var results = dbcon.Query<TestSubject>("SELECT * FROM TestTable WHERE first_name LIKE @a", new {a = "%" + searchTerm + "%"});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, but that isn't the problem :/

Answer (score 1):

The problem apparently was that I used a TextMeshPro-Inputfield (instead of the generic one from Unity) for the searchText string. So even though it looked the same when printed, it actually wasn't. Maybe it uses a different encoding or different cultural settings? Anyways, using a "normal" input field works. Thanks for all the help and valuable suggestions!

EDIT: The error can also be avoided when actually getting the string from TMP_Inputfield.text instead of TMP_Text.text.

Comment: hmmm but when you looked at it in the debugger it had the value?  In that case you probably had to do a `searchTerm.ToString().Trim()` to get it to work.  It seems strange that your function takes a string as a parameter and you did not get any errors or warnings.

Comment: yeah, I trimmed it, I converted to lower case, etc. - I don't know what the difference of the text.text string & the inputfield.text are, since in the debugger they looked exactly the same  maybe I should try to compare/print char by char & check again.. but for now I'm just relieved that the problem is "solved" & that it had nothing to do with sqlite :P